# How to reset bashrc in Ubuntu to remove user-written export $path

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have added some environment variable as an export path to bash shell. Unfortuanately, I did it wrong and now I can't login to my account in Ubuntu.

Is it possible to remove these export commands from .bashrc, or can we directly replace this 
bashrc to the one defined by the system like default?

I can't login even after entering the correct password, but at the same time I can login through guest account.
This might give some idea about the problem. I got this using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> at the login screen.

```
Last login: Wed Jan 22 13:17:57 CET 2014 on tty1
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.0-35-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/

-bash: export: `:': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `usr/local/SHTOOLS2.8/modules': not a valid identifier
-bash: export: `:': not a valid identifier
-bash: export' `usr/local/SHTOOLS2.8/lib': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: You've set environment variables incorrectly in your `~/.bashrc`.  Remove spaces around `=` in `export` commands.

Comment: You could `ftp` your `.bashrc`; fix it; `ftp` it back.

Comment: In case he has an ftpd running ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get write access to the misconfigured start script (`.bashrc`).  Can that be achieved via the guest account?  I doubt it.  Otherwise just edit your file using `sudo pico /home/user/.bashrc`.

You can always get write access by starting a runtime system from a Ubuntu boot disk.  That on-the-fly system which starts then can mount the hard disks so you can then modify the `.bashrc` in question.  I pray you are not using a crypted home directory.

You can also try out whether you can log in to your account via `ssh` (you need to have an sshd installed and running for that of course).  If you can connect but the login stays broken, maybe you can at least execute commands via `ssh`:  `ssh user@host date` (using `date` just for testing purposes).  If at least this functions, we can start patching your broken script file via commands.

Comment: I am able to use control + alter + f1 and login using my admin account, also sudo is working there, so I guess, write access would not be a problem

Comment: Then just try `sudo pico /home/user/.bashrc` and fix the problem using that very easy-to-use editor.

Comment: This was the most accurate answer I got so far, tried a lot on web but didn't get any precise answers.
I had those lines added in .profile file at the end.
Using pico command, I just removed those lines and it worked like a charm. Linux is a magical world.
Thanks

Comment: @ChP: and the best part of this magic: it's clearly documented and available... little by little you'll discover how everything works, and can do it because nothing is hidden. It's free, so you are free to look at the code, and even modify it if the need arises. Or just enjoy its community, very helpful (especially if you ask precise and clear questions, about the problem you need to solve, not any method you think you should use to do it. That way people know the problem, and the solution will often surprise you and take you in new and wonderful directions). Welcome to the Gnu+Linux world!

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:
(1) You need to re-gain system access
(2) You need to fix .bashrc

Solution:
(1) Problem#1:Regaining Access 
(1)(a) If there is another user with sudoers permissions (i.e. the user can execute "sudo" to execute commands as root), then have that user log in and you will have access to the system to perform the solution to Problem#2.
(1)(b) if you do not have another user account on the system, you will need to boot from an Ubuntu or other live CD and mount the file system for repair operations to Problem#2.  That is outside of the scope of this specific problem, but there are plenty of docs to that effect online.

(2) Problem#2:Repairing .bashrc
(2)(a) The simplest approach is to make a backup copy of .bashrc in your home directory, calling the bad file something like myBadbashrc.  Then you can replace the file with a fresh .bashrc from /etc/skel or whereever your particular system gets its new-account template from.
(2)(b) If you don't feel like replacing the above file, you can do edits and continue testing through iterations.

(3) A footnote on .bashrc or other account maintenance.  Always test with a TEST account.  if you can't do that, then login under another terminal WHILE you are still logged in to make sure things work right.  The good news: We have ALL done what you've just done and learned this lesson the hard way. ;-)

--Sam

Comment: Thanks, I solved the problem by repairing.profile file to remove those lines I had added previously.